# Bash script executing parameterised command with path

Tags: bash

I'm very confused about calling a command in bash with paths as parameters, coming from bash variables.

I've narrowed down the question to this:

Given a directory with the following contents:

```
KOSTUNRIX:i18n jand$ ls -al
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  6 jand  staff   204 Mar  6 15:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 jand  staff   102 Mar  6 10:27 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 jand  staff  3159 Mar  6 10:47 README.md
-rwxr--r--  1 jand  staff  4504 Mar  6 15:47 diff.sh
-rwxr--r--  1 jand  staff  4080 Mar  6 13:43 takeIn.sh
-rwxr--r--  1 jand  staff   558 Mar  6 15:51 test.sh
```

The script `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ $# -gt 1 ]]
do
  key="$1"

  case ${key} in
      --from)
      echo "--from" $2
      from="$2"
      shift
      ;;
      --to)
      echo "--to" $2
      to="$2"
      shift
      ;;
      -c|--command)
      echo "--command" $2
      command="$2"
      shift
      ;;
      *)
      # unknown option
      echo ${key} "- huh?"
      ;;
  esac
  shift
done

pwd
echo $command
iCommand=${command/"\$from"/\"$from\"}
echo $iCommand
iCommand=${iCommand/"\$to"/\"$to\"}
echo ${iCommand}
${iCommand}
cp "./README.md" "./README.mdFORCED"
```

executing `test.sh` gives:

```
KOSTUNRIX:i18n jand$ ./test.sh --command "cp \$from \$to" --from ./README.md --to ./README.md2
--command cp $from $to
--from ./README.md
--to ./README.md2
[...]/i18n
cp $from $to
cp "./README.md" $to
cp "./README.md" "./README.md2"
cp: "./README.md": No such file or directory
KOSTUNRIX:i18n jand$ ls -al
total 48
drwxr-xr-x  7 jand  staff   238 Mar  6 15:57 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 jand  staff   102 Mar  6 10:27 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 jand  staff  3159 Mar  6 10:47 README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 jand  staff  3159 Mar  6 15:57 README.mdFORCED
-rwxr--r--  1 jand  staff  4504 Mar  6 15:47 diff.sh
-rwxr--r--  1 jand  staff  4080 Mar  6 13:43 takeIn.sh
-rwxr--r--  1 jand  staff   558 Mar  6 15:51 test.sh
```

After gathering the arguments (`--from`, `--to`, `--command`), I output for debugging:

- `pwd` --> `[...]/i18n`
- `echo $command` --> `cp $from $to`
- `echo $iCommand` --> `cp "./README.md" $to` (from replaced)
- `echo $iCommand` --> `cp "./README.md" "./README.md2"` (to replaced)

Next, I execute the last output. What bugs me is that this doesn't work. The response is:

```
cp: "./README.md": No such file or directory
```

Yet, when I copy/paste the previous string in the terminal, it works. And as a double check, I pasted a variation of that command in the script too, at the last line, and that works too, as you can see in the `ls` afterwards (`README.mdFORCED` exists).

Whatever a try with backquotes, `${}`, `$()`, I can't get this to work.

(Note that is the simplest version of this question I came up with. The actual issue arose with doing this with paths that contain spaces -- but I gather that when this becomes clear, that might be resolved too).

Using absolute paths gives the same result:

```
KOSTUNRIX:i18n jand$ ./test.sh --command "cp \$from \$to" --from `pwd`/README.md --to `pwd`/README.md2
--command cp $from $to
--from /[...]/i18n/README.md
--to /[...]/i18n/README.md2
/[...]/i18n
cp $from $to
cp "/[...]/i18n/README.md" $to
cp "/[...]/i18n/README.md" "/[...]/i18n/README.md2"
cp: "/[...]/i18n/README.md": No such file or directory
```

Again, executing the copy/pasted command by hand

```
cp "/[...]/i18n/README.md" "/[...]/i18n/README.md2"
```

does work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you print the result of pwd?

Comment: It's in the output both times above. `pwd` --> `[...]/i18n` both times (`[..]` is the path to the directory on my disk).

Comment: Notice the quotes in the `cp` error? They aren't getting stripped. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for why this approach (command in a string) is problematic.

Comment: Etan, is that link correct? That page doesn't seem to address this issue at all, nor "command in a string"?

Comment: Etan, the quotes in the `cp` error are there also in the `echo`, and are intentional -- to deal with possible blanks in arguments (which doesn't work ... but that doesn't seem to be this issue at this point, is it?) Or is it?

Comment: BashFAQ #48 (on why `eval` is risky to use, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) and BashFAQ #50 (for best practices on programatically assembling commands, at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) are more on-point than #1 (which is focused on file IO).

Comment: @JanDockx, with respect to the quotes you're trying to add during the substitution -- that can help against non-malicious problems, like whitespace, but doesn't do you any good against an actively malicious filename (or a bug that creates random junk that looks like one). I've actually been somewhere where the "random junk" thing happened on a production server responsible for maintaining historical archives, and a great deal of data loss occurred as a result.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Indeed. Wrong link. Sorry for the confusion everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Doing string substitution on code is always Bad Idea. Just as [Bobby Tables can wreck havoc on SQL](http://xkcd.com/327/), his cousin Jimmy `/tmp/$(rm -rf /)/` can wreck havoc on shell.

Now, there's a slightly safer way to do what you want: Don't mutate the code; instead, pass arguments to it through the environment.

That is to say:

```
from="$from" to="$to" eval "$command"
```

...**WITHOUT** changing `$command` from what a trusted user gave you. Then, it all depends on `$command` to be written safely: Should the value be `'cp "$from" "$to"'`, you'll be safe. (However, this is how that command would be correctly written in shell in general -- if folks are in the habit of writing `cp $from $to` in your organization, y'all have bigger problems).

---

Now, if you insist on doing string substitution on code, you can do that too -- but you'll need your shell to be bash, or something else with the `printf %q` extension, to sanitize the variables to be `eval`-safe, and you'll need to ensure that the places where substitution is taking place is **not** quoted in the `command` given. (In this case, `'cp $from $to'` would actually be desirable).

```
printf -v from_str %q "$from"
printf -v to_str %q "$to"
iCommand=${command/'$from'/$from_str}
iCommand=${iCommand/'$to'/$to_str}
eval "$iCommand"
```

I rather strongly advise against this approach, since you're requiring users to write code that would be buggy in any other context -- anyone doing a security audit would be prone to flagging this script's users unless they dug in far enough to see what was being done to make the usage safe. Alternately, you could use different substitution variables -- ie. `@from@` and `@to@` -- to make it clear that the semantics at play aren't those of upstream bash.

Answer (score -1):

Placing a variable on a line by itself is not typically enough to execute a command stored inside that variable.

Try `eval $iCommand` instead.

Comment: No, don't. It's bad advice.

Comment: Using `eval` on user-supplied input strings is a massive security hole.  Even if you don't care about security in particular, it adds a huge complication in that many things will not work as expected unless you add correspondingly huge sanitization steps.

Comment: Also, it is in fact not true that a variable alone on a line cannot be used to execute a simple command. http://ideone.com/hcmN3E

Comment: "typically", I think, was enough of a hedge -- as the robust way to execute a simple command from a variable (without using `eval`) is to have that variable be an array rather than a scalar.